# Python Group By

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am trying a simple calculation. I have a data frame with 1000 observations for different years and want to calculate the mean of a variable by year. I've used the "groupby" statement, but the resulting means only occur once per year. How can I have repeating mean values for all 1000 observations in the original dataset? Is there a way to do this without merging grouped results to the original data frame?

Edit: using data from [this](https://www.marsja.se/python-pandas-groupby-tutorial-examples/) link as an example, if I have the following:

[image]

Is there a way to calculate this mean in the original data and have it for every row?

[image]

Comment: There are many examples of how to do `groupby` operations in Python. If you are not already, I would suggest using the Pandas library. Here is a walkthrough/tutorial: https://www.marsja.se/python-pandas-groupby-tutorial-examples/. Otherwise, It'd be helpful if you showed the code you have so far.

Comment: I just added an example using the data from this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best method will be to calculate mean salary against as you have done in 1st dataframe example and then use joins,mapping,apply etc. to get desired dataframe.

1. **Join**
   You can use right outer join to merge both dataframes in your examples, considering 1st dataframe as left and 2nd datafarame as right. [**See the documentation**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).
2. By using **apply**:

   dat['salary'] = dat['rank'].apply(lambda x :93876.437500 if x =='Assoc Prof' else ... and so on )
3. **Map**
   Its also similar to apply

   dat['salary'] = dat['rank'].map('Assoc Prof':93876.437500 , '': , '' : ...and so on)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a partitionBy method. This can be done in pandas using groupBy and the transform method as seen in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905335/aggregation-over-partition-pandas-dataframe